# example of a discrete set which is closed

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

How to show this set $A= \{-n + 1/n: n=2,3,4,\ldots\}$ is closed in $\mathbb R$ with usual metric?

I guess it is a discrete set and has no limit points but I want to show rigorously, may be its complement is open?
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your set has one and only one point on each interval $[-n,-n+1]$ ($n\in\mathbb{N}\setminus\{1\}$). Therefore, if a sequence of points of $A$ converges, then it must be quasi-constant, that is, it must be constant after a certain order. So, it must converge to another point of $A$. Therefore, $A$ is closed.

Comment: didn't understand your explanation

Comment: @miosaki I am using the fact that a set $A$ is closed if and only if when a sequence $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ of elements of $A$ converges to some $l$, then $l\in A$. Is it clear now?

Comment: it was not $n+1/n$ but $-n+1/n$ sorry

Comment: @miosaki I have adapted my answer to the new version of your question.

Answer (score 2):

The complement of $A$ is the union of (countably many) open intervals:
$$
A^c=(-\infty,3/2) \cup \bigcup_{n\ge 2}\left(n+\frac{1}{n},n+1+\frac{1}{n+1}\right),
$$
i.e., $A^c$ is open. Hence $A$ is closed.

Moreover it is a discrete set because for each $a \in A$ you have 
$$
A \cap \left(a-\frac{1}{a},a+\frac{1}{a}\right)=\{a\}.
$$
In particular, it has no limit points.

Comment: what exactly... can you please write explicitly the union?

Comment: for only {n} I can write

Comment: it was not $n+1/n$ but $-n+1/n$ sorry

Comment: You can use the same reasoning

Comment: but complement representation will be changed or.. same?

Comment: What do you think about?