# Is the set $\{\sqrt2,2\sqrt2,3\sqrt2,...,n\sqrt2, ...\}$ closed in $\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: general-topology

Is the set $\{\sqrt2,2\sqrt2,3\sqrt2,...,n\sqrt2, ...\}$ closed in $\mathbb{R}$?
My attempt:
Let $S=\{\sqrt2,2\sqrt2,3\sqrt2,...,n\sqrt2, ...\}$
So $\mathbb{R}\backslash S=(-\infty,\sqrt2) \cup (
\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty} (k\sqrt2,(k+1)\sqrt2)
)$
which is the union of a countably infinite number of open sets so $\mathbb{R}\backslash S$ is open and $S$ is closed.

Is my working flawed? Is $S$ even closed in the first place?

Comment: It is closed and your proof is perfect!

Comment: Looks fine. By the way, you don't need the collection to be countable. Any union of open sets is open.

Comment: Okay, thanks~ I wasn't sure because I don't have an answer key

Comment: Recently learnt about countable and uncountable sets so I wanted to identify them correctly ^^

Comment: The positive integers $\mathbb{Z}_{>0}$ are closed in $\mathbb{R}$, and the map $x \mapsto x\sqrt{2}$ is a homeomorphism.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$S$ is closed and the working is not flawed. Note that any union of open sets is open, not just a countably infinite union of open sets

Comment: You might benefit also to learn the idea of a "discrete set". For example, this sequence is similar to yours: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2415333